# Adding products in assotiave array

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a problem. In a certain site, I have to show which products the buyer has bought.  I have also taken each of the categories of the product, put it into assotiave array, and then I place it into a variable. When I add products from a same category, all works well. However, when I add products from different categories, there are problems. My question is: does anyone have an idea how I can add products from different categories into a same array, from the existing code?

```
            foreach ($acne_arr as $key => $value) {
                $message_e .= '<tr>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000;height:30px;" align="center"></td>
                    <td style=" font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000;height:30px;">'.$value['PRODUCT'].'</td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000;height:30px;" align="center">'.$value['price'].'</td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px; color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height:30px;">
                        <input type="text" style="width:37px; background:none;border:none;font-weight:normal;" value="'.$value['qty'].'" readonly />
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px; color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height:30px;">
                        <input style="width:37px; background:none; border:none; font-weight:normal;" type="text" value="'.$value['amt'].'" readonly />
                    </td>
                </tr>';
                  $product = json_encode($acne_arr);

               }
                    foreach ($acb_arr as $key => $value) {
                $message_e .= '<tr>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000;height:30px;" align="center"></td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000;height:30px;">'.$value['PRODUCT'].'</td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000; height:30px;" align="center">'.$value['price'].'</td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px; color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height:30px;">
                        <input type="text" style="width:37px; background:none;border:none;font-weight:normal;" value="'.$value['qty'].'" readonly />
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px; color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height:30px;">
                        <input style="width:37px; background:none; border:none; font-weight:normal;" type="text" value="'.$value['amt'].'" readonly />
                    </td>
                </tr>';
                $product1 = json_encode($acb_arr);
                $product = $product1;
              }
foreach ($abh_arr as $key => $value) {
                $message_e .= '<tr>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000;height:30px;" align="center"></td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000;height:30px;">'.$value['PRODUCT'].'</td>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:14px; color:#000; height:30px;" align="center">'.$value['price'].'</td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px; color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height:30px;">
                        <input type="text" style="width:37px; background:none;border:none;font-weight:normal;" value="'.$value['qty'].'" readonly />
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:12px; color:#000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height:30px;">
                        <input style="width:37px; background:none; border:none; font-weight:normal;" type="text" value="'.$value['amt'].'" readonly />
                    </td>
                </tr>';
                $product2 = json_encode($abh_arr);
                $product .= $product2;
                }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you say what problems you encounter with the different category? Also there seems to be a lot repetition. Perhaps you can create a template and loop through each associative array of products to create the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `array` to add products from many categories like

```
$books = array(1,2,3,4);
$pens = array(1,2,3,4);
$others = array(1,2,3,4);
$mainArray = array(
    'books' => $books,
    'pens' => $pens,
    'others' => $others
);
```

If you need to add new product in any category

```
$mainArray['books'][] = $newBook;
$mainArray['pens'][] = $newPen;
```

It will add new product to new free index